# Starting Visual Studio project with a Relase Build itself

Tags: c++, visual-studio, managed-c++

If I decide to start with a Release Build itself in the beginning of my Visual Studio based C++ project, what are the various pitfalls (if any) that I should be aware of? I already know how to debug a release build by applying the necessary changes in the project properties.

- Are there any issues which doesn't seem to pop up in Release builds,
  but Debug builds can highlight the same?
- Will it matter if I have a small project or a large one?
- Also, will it matter if I am dealing with Managed code, other than
  native C++ code.
- What about the optimizations which are turned on by default in the
  release builds. Will they hamper or hide the bugs in Release builds?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: yes, yes,  yes, [optimizations for speed and size - yes, they will hide bugs]

Comment: But i will write up an answer that might help.

Comment: @selbie: thanks..awaiting your comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "start with a Release Build" or why that is an issue.

When you start a new Visual Studio project, it generates two configurations for it.  Debug and Release. At any time, you can flip the configuration between Debug and Release without issue.

A Debug build is one that has compiler optimizations turned off. The default linkage to the C/C++ runtime is to the Debug MSVCRT*.DLL files.  With a debug build, it comes a lot easier to do line by line debugging since none of the code or variables have been optimized out.  You typically do not give DEBUG builds to customers.

A Release build is one that has compiler optimizations turned on. Debugging is slightly harder since much of the code is inlined and optimized. There's not always a corresponding "line of code" to each block of generated assembly. Hence, when stepping through line by line through a function in a Release build with the debugger, you might observe some very weird effects (variables not visible in the watch window, the instruction pointer arrow moving to unexpected lines, etc...).

Each configuration can have it's optimization settings, global DEFINEs, and other compiler/linker settings int the [project properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z15yzzew.aspx) of your Visual Studio project.

FWIW, in our product group, we actually have three configurations: Debug, Release, and Ship.  The Ship and Release builds have the same compiler optimizations, except in the Ship build, we declare `SHIP_BUILD` as a define.  Certain code blocks are excluded under `#ifndef SHIP_BUILD` sections of the code. These are usually test hooks not meant for customers. Our test automation typically runs on a mix of Debug and Retail configurations.

Comment: thanks for the info. Just wanted to know all the pros and cons.